# TextBoxFor and DefaultModelBinder aren't formatting/parsing fr-FR correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, model-binding

The TextBoxFor HTML helper does not respect the DisplayFormatAttribute but the EditorFor does on double values.  Likewise the DefaultModelBinder doesn't bind a properly formatted double with the thousand seperator.

I can display the property formatted double with the EditorFor but then it won't bind.  I would prefer to display the property formatted string in a text box and be able to post and bind it.

Has anyone experienced this issue and resolved it?

Adding a sample solution here - 
https://bitbucket.org/chief7/asp.net-mvc-3-localization-issue

Answer (score 0):

Scott from my team found the following blog post by Haack.  This was exactly our problem.  I hope they fix this issue soon.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx

I have also implemented the fix in the sample solution on bitbucket.org.